# how to setup SMTP on new Windows Server 2008 for email to/from a Visual Basic 2010 app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, smtp, windows-server-2008, pop3

QUESTION 1 - Outgoing email:
How do I configure Windows to send out email that is stored in \inetpub\mailroot\pickup\

My Visual Basic app stores email files into pickup\ when sending outbound email.

QUESTION 2 - Incoming email:
How do I configure Windows to receiving incoming email to a directory? Like in \inetpub\mailroot\mailbox...

My Visual Basic app continually monitors the directory, and reads email files as they come in.

This all worked great in my previous Windows Server 2003.

But I see no way to add POP3 mailbox directories in Win Serv 2008.

Comment: I can't see what this question has to do with `programming questions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager" but not new "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager". Be sure that you added "SMTP Server Tools" as server feature.